# What does it mean when we say that an element in $L^p$ is Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $E$. When we say that $f\in L^p(E,\mathcal{B}(E),\mu)$ is Lipschitz, does it mean that there is a Lipschitz function $g$ in the equivalent class $f$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to think so.

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $